# Periscope Comments Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to achieve the same animation as in Periscope comments[image: sampleimage].

> The way I am doing it is:  I am having a `ListView` . With the
>   animation fade-out for the first Visible Child inside the ListView.
>   But this does not seems to be working.

Kindly give me suggestion on how to achieve this . Thanks!

Comment: This was helpful : http://frogermcs.github.io/recyclerview-animations-androiddevsummit-write-up/

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to a 2 year old question but might help someone else in future.

You can do this by using [Recycler View](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) in combination with [Count Down Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and [Alpha Animation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html)

This is how it goes.

1. In Adapter inside onBindViewHolder method, create a CountDownTimer instance binded to every message/text view created. So that every message posted has a timer attached to it.

   ```
       new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000){ //(timer_duration, timer_interval)
                   @Override
                   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                       //runs every second (1000 ms)
                   }
                   @Override
                   public void onFinish() {
                       //Do your operations when timer is finised
                       setFadeAnimation(viewHolder.comment_layout_container);
                       userCommentList.remove(userComment);

              viewHolder.comment_layout_container.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   }
               }.start();
   ```
2. When timer finishes for a particular message/text posted, then inside onFinish() you can invoke a function that will fade out the view. Declare a variable global or local whatever suits your needs for FADE_DURATION.
   `int FADE_DURATION = 1000; // in milliseconds`

   `private void setFadeAnimation(LinearLayout view) {
   /*sets animation from complete opaque state(1.0f) to complete transparent state(0.0f)*/
      AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
      anim.setDuration(FADE_DURATION);
      view.startAnimation(anim);`

   }

[periscope like comment view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUKbQ.png)

**NOTE** - This is the way I managed to do it and I am just 3-4 months into Android Development. This is closer to periscope style comment section layout. Obviously there is always room for improvements. Atlast I want to thank SO community.

[image]

Comment: After your fade animation, you should probably remove the item from the list.

Comment: that's right. I didn't include that part because OP just asked for Animation part. But I ll edit the answer. Thanks for feedback.